# For "another" example

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

In formal writing, if I have 2 examples to depict what I said earlier, can I start writing a sentence using 'for another example' form after explaining my first example using 'for example'? More clearly:

> for example, bla bla bla.... .
>
> for another example, bla bla bla ... .

is this construction suitable in formal writing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should not say *for another example*.

The phrase *for example* does not tell the reader *what* you are about to say, it tells the reader *why* you are saying it. This is why we use the preposition *for*, just as we might say *for better understanding* or *for comic relief*, and it is why we do not say *for **an** example*. *Example* is not used as the 'countable' noun but as a generic quality attributed to what follows: it *exemplifies* what has gone before.

Answer (score 3):

In formal writing or speaking, there's no need to put *for* for the second time when it's quite obvious that you are mentioning one more example.

> For example: blah...blah...blah... 
>   (And...) Another example (is): blah...blah...blah...

Answer (score 2):

"For example" is used before mentioning an example:

> Many countries, for example Japan and Mexico, has a lot of earthquakes

To mention other examples you may say "**As another example**, balah blah.."

> For example, blah blah blah...
>   As another example, blah blah...

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

For instance...
Another example would be...

This will help avoid repetition.